# How create a POST with JsonArray in body

Tags: android

I want to send this json body to server using **POST METHOD**

```
   {
      "donatations": [
                       {
       "campaignId": "string",
       "name": "string",
       "type": 0, 
       "donationValue": 0 
       }
   ],
   "profileId": "string",
   "creditCardId": "string",
   "isPaidFees": true,
   "isRequestDonatation": true
   "amountFees": 0,
   "totalDonationAmount": 0, 
   "institutionId": "string" 
    }
```

I tried many solutions available on web but most of them tell to format the string and sent to server. Is there any correct way to send this body to server?.

I usually do this to send simple Strings to server

```
 JsonObject dados = new JsonObject();
                dados.addProperty("profileId", sessionManager.getUsuario().getId());
                dados.addProperty("name", scanResult.cardholderName.toString());
```

And send the JsonObject as Body of my POST

please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to start with valid JSON to begin with. Also, show us the code that you created that didn't work, explain what _exactly_ didn't work, and _maybe_ we can help fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JsonObj/Array API to create one:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
JSONObject objFromArray = new JSONObject();
objFromArray.put("key", "value");
objFromArray.put("ke2y", "value");
array.add(objFromArray);
}
obj.put("child", array);
obj.put("normalObject", "another value");
```

You will have a object such:

```
{"child": [ {/**obj*/}, /** 9 more objs*/ ], "normalObject":"anther value" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically use Spring and Java POJO's to send/receive data as you have mentioned. Create a new Spring Java application. Once you have a basic Spring application, you can now model your data structure with POJO's. Something like the following should work for your data structure:

```
public class Profile() {
    private String profileId;
    private String creditCardId;
    private boolean isPaidFees;
    private List<Donations> donations;
    //etc. plus getters and setters
}

public class Donations(){
    private String campaignId;
    private String name;
    private int type;
    private float donationValue;
    //etc. plus getters and setters
}
```

Now that you have your data structures defined in Java POJO's you can create a REST interface using spring that will map it for you. This can read in JSon and convert it to your POJO or it can get your POJO and return it as JSon.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public Profile getProfile(@RequestBody Profile profile) {
    System.out.println(profile.profileId);
    return profile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a pojo if you are only creating the object to post it. Here is a very simple way:

```
    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject arrayItem = new JSONObject();

    try {
        //PUT VALUES TO THE ARRAYITEM. 
        //YOU WILL NEED TO LOOP HERE IF YOU HAVE MORE THAN 1 ITEM IN THE JSONARRAY
        arrayItem.put("campaignId", "string");
        arrayItem.put("name", "string");
        arrayItem.put("type", 0);
        arrayItem.put("donationValue", 0);

        //PUT THE JSONOBJECT ITEM INSIDE THE JSONARRAY
        array.put(arrayItem);

        //PUT THE JSONARRAY INSIDE THE MAIN JSONOBJECT
        mainObject.put("myArray", array);

        //KEEP PUTTING THE REMAINING ITEMS INSIDE THE MAIN JSONOBJECT
        mainObject.put("profileId", "string");
        mainObject.put("creditCardId", "string");
        mainObject.put("isPaidFees", true);
        mainObject.put("isRequestDonatation", true);
        mainObject.put("amountFees", 0);
        mainObject.put("totalDonationAmount", 0);
        mainObject.put("institutionId", "string");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now you can send the mainObject normally the way you used to do it before.